# Fulltext for innoDB? or a good solution for php app

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, full-text-search

I have a table I want to run a fulltext search on, but it is currently innoDB and is using a lot of foreign keys for other kinds of queries.

Should I make like a 1:1 "meta-data" table that is myisam for fulltext?

Also I am reading some things that say that fulltext corrupts MySQL tables pretty randomly?  I dunno, the articles are a couple years old, maybe they've fixed that in 5+?

If not what's a good solution for searching?  Zend_Lucene seems cool but slow, even with caching, for the client's large tables and autocomplete functionality et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look at [sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) for search routine.

Answer (score 0):

Or join fulltext data 1:1 InnoDb to MyISAM ;)